# Create database using script at the default path?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-scripts

I've generated a script of a database in SQL Server 2008. The generated script has the hardcoded path of where the database would be created. I don't want this path to be hardcoded, I want this path to use the default of the database engine the script is running on.

Here is the small portion of the script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [POS] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'POS', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\POS.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'POS_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\POS_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

The path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\POS.mdf` might not exist on all computers that's why I want it to be chosen by the database engine

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply create the database and then adjust all the needed properties directly in files

```
CREATE DATABASE [POS] 
GO
ALTER DATABASE POS MODIFY FILE 
( NAME = N'POS' , SIZE = 3048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE POS MODIFY FILE 
( NAME = N'POS_log' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: yeah, I was already trying to choose it as best but stackoverflow was not allowing me to choose that early

Answer (score 16):

Why don't use just:

```
CREATE DATABASE [POS];
```

This will create the database with all the default settings (including paths). You may alter any setting you like later on.

Comment: It will use POS and POS_log as defaults. In my case at least.