# sql modify file statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a SQL issue and have tried multiple combinations to no avail. I've tried commas, and also semicolons, after the first two ), all three ), just the last ), on all of these. No such luck. Please help me fix the query. Thanks in advance!

I have done due diligence and came across several sites (I can only post two links because of reputatoin) these:
[Create database using script at the default path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837207/sql-server-create-database-using-script-how-to-create-database-at-default-path)
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=148732

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE
(
    NAME = location_cust_db_data1,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
)
(
    NAME = location_cust_db_data2,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
)
(
    NAME = location_cust_db_data3,
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
)
GO
```

---

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data1, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data2, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data3, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO
```

---

THIS WORKS, but very cumbersome to do 20 files.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = location_cust_db_data1,
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)


USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = location_cust_db_data2,
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO

USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = location_cust_db_data3,
MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third option is closest - each modification has to be in a separate `ALTER DATABASE` command, but you can leave out the `USE` statements since you're always running from `MASTER` :

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data1, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO

ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data2, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO

ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db
MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data3, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)
GO

..etc
```

Answer (score 0):

if I got the issue right, so this one would help you

```
begin
use master;
declare @com nvarchar(1024);
set @com='ALTER DATABASE location_cust_db MODIFY FILE (NAME = location_cust_db_data';
declare @i int;
set @i=1;
while(@i<20) begin
      set @com=@com+str(@i)+' ,MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED);'
      exec (@com);
      set @i=@i+1;
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use [location_cust_db]
GO

declare csDBFiles cursor local fast_forward for
select
    'ALTER DATABASE [' + DB_NAME() + '] MODIFY FILE (NAME = [' + name + '], MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED)'
from
    sys.database_files

open csDBFiles

declare @stmt varchar(2000)

fetch next from csDBFiles into @stmt
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    print @stmt
    print 'GO'
    exec(@stmt)

    fetch next from csDBFiles into @stmt
end

close csDBFiles
deallocate csDBFiles
GO
```

Comment: Possibly `where type_desc = 'ROWS'` at cursor declaration, or any other condition(s) if necessary.